# Properly setting up a feed

Tags: categories, feed

I have tried to setup a feed following the instructions here: https://wordpress.org/support/article/wordpress-feeds/

[image: My WP reading settings]

[image: Post categories]

According to the instructions, https://sport-1a.de/category/Blog-Artikel/feed should return the proper feed. However, I am getting 404 - page not found. Trying the category slug (https://sport-1a.de/category/blogpost/feed) didn't help either.

How can I fix this?

Comment: can you embed the images directly into the question using the image function rathe than google drive?

Comment: Visiting https://sport-1a.de/category/Blog-Artikel/ redirects to the homepage, are you sure that there is a category archive at that location? And that it is a native post archive, not a page with a page template that lists posts?

Comment: Got your images. 

It is a page with a widget that lists posts. I have to admit that there are probably a lot of things I don't know about Wordpress. I also wouldn't know how to create a native post archive. I guess I will simply google it. :)

Comment: I found that I have to use "kategorie" and not "category" in the feed link. Sorry, my bad. I wasn't aware that WP would localize automatically generated links (although it seems quite logical).

Comment: The `pre_get_posts` filter is super useful for changing post archives without having to create templates with secondary loops, it solves a lot of stumbling blocks

Answer (score 1):

1. Feed links have to use the category slug (not the name) ("Blog-Artikel" --> "blogpost" in the case of the site in question)
2. Feed links have to conform with the localization of the page offering the feed (i.e. "category" --> "kategorie" for a WP site with a Germain domain. Funny enough, the WP site language of the site in question is set to "English")